# Python sleep for a process goes into indefinite sleep

Tags: python, macos

I have a python process which spawns multiple other processes in background. I wish I can do multi threading but the underlying library which my code uses is not reliable in multi threaded environment.

My background python processes need to wait for almost an hour for an event. The only way to check if that event has occurred is using a polling method.

So, I have a code which sleeps for a min (`time.sleep(60)`) and wakes up and does some work. Polls few things and goes to sleep.

However, I have experienced many times one/more threads go into deep sleep and never come out. What could be the reason? Is there a better way to do this. (I don't wait on IO)

```
 while True:
    if event:
      #do lot of stuff
      break
    else:
      #do some stuff
    time.sleep(60)
```

(The platform is OSX)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is being caused by `sleep` and not by something else the code is doing? For example, you might not have accounted for some case in which the loop should break, and so it keeps on sleeping.

Comment: `but the underlying library which my code uses is not reliable in multi threaded environment` but it is reliable multi-process? What library are you using and what are you trying to do? Where does `event` come from?

Comment: Library is some internal library to my workplace. The probability is high that it is multiprocess safe. Or I gonna be the one to discover the bug. :(I am looking to catch event like device is connected to the bus/a file is created by user in a particular location.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an infinite loop. 
 
`while TRUE` is always `TRUE`, so it stays in that loop. 
 
Only when `if event` is `TRUE` there will be a `break`.

The problem in you code seems to be that `if event` is always `FALSE`, it is never `TRUE`. So you stay in your while loop.

Comment: I think so, as no variable in there was signaled `true`